# This duplicate - Are we missing something?

Tags: discussion

Earlier this month I asked my first question on this site. See: [I think my Mac swallowed Facebook and Twitter - How to get them back?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368131/i-think-my-mac-swallowed-facebook-and-twitter-how-to-get-them-back)

Today I came back and found it had been closed as a Duplicate of this question: [Facebook sharing from Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343768/facebook-sharing-from-safari)

I disagreed with this and flagged it as follows:

> This is not a duplicate. The other question is about Facebook sharing
>   from Safari. I don't even use Safari. My question is about the share
>   menu in macOS itself. See my screenshots for clarification. Please
>   reconsider this decision as there will be other users who do NOT use
>   Safari and share directly from macOS. Thank you.

I then noticed my flag was marked with the following comment by someone (don't know who):

> helpful - Pointing the question to another is harmless unless you need
>   another answer. Can you ask on meta or in chat if I’m missing
>   something but I see no need to reverse the close link.

Now I'm asking on meta to see if we are all missing something?

Thank you for your deliberation. :)

Comment: I've edited the selected answer to mark why and when we reversed the close direction. Thanks so much for the time to review this request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up on Meta!

My main thought on the close was the fact, that sharing with FB/Twitter was fully removed in Mojave, for all applications including Finder. So whether somebody is missing the functionality in Safari, or in Finder, or in any other application relying on the standard sharing functionality available in earlier versions, the answer is always the same: the feature got removed in Mojave.

Now, the questions are still distinct, I agree. But the idea behind closing as duplicate is to avoid duplication of answers, so if several questions basically ask the same thing from different angles, all leading to the same answer, closing as duplicate is the way to go.

PS: the fun part is that the answer you got is actually better than the answer to the original question, and your question is broader as well. So reversing the duplicate relation and closing the original as a duplicate might be an option (which I won’t pursue for the moment because it‘s a few minutes past midnight here and I need some sleep first :-))

P.P.S: we've reversed the close direction based on the quality of the answer and the quality of the question with images and better wording. Thanks for the patience while we got everyone on board with what was missing initially.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand that. This way we avoid duplicate answers and sometimes the older question can be the one that is closed as a duplicate of the newer one if that serves the site better. That makes sense when I think about it. Thank you and good night. :)